# How to divide 15V to 12V and 3V?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I need to get both 12V and 3V from the same 15V source as outputs, but can't seem to do it. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: For what purpose? In case of signals you can use resistor voltage dividers but in case you need to supply something then that's not recommended and you'd have to use regulators.

Comment: for both power supply to opamp  and to add voltage to the output signal so it does not fall bellow 0V

Comment: @Joseph So you need these to be low-impedance voltage sources?

Comment: In case of supplies you need to specify how much current they should draw. Anyway, how to design a random voltage regulator is too broad a question. In that case you need to make an attempt first, after which it is fine to ask for a review of your schematic.

Comment: @Joseph Lundin is guiding you well. Just saying "opamps" isn't enough. We need to know what those opamps are and what they are driving. Or else you need to specify what the worst-case current loading is likely to be, if you can work that out. In broad stretches, each opamp will require a few mA. And they often cannot drive more than 10 mA to about maybe 25 mA (with some exceptional cases where the output can drive a lot more.) But you need to total all this up because it matters in deciding between a switcher or a linear.

Comment: added the full circuit

Comment: @Joseph So the [LM258](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosbt3j/snosbt3j.pdf) and your circuit won't require a lot of current. And the 3 V output is also lightly loaded. That's good because it means you can easily get away with a very simple linear supply arrangement.

Comment: @jonk yes can you help tho?

Comment: Can you not just use linear regulators to step the voltage down?

Comment: @Joseph Only generally. I still don't know what you require. There's no specification for your input sine source (I'm guessing 'dangerous voltage' right now.) And there's no specification for what you expect in terms of allowed error/bias/noise at the ADC input. But in general, a simple linear 12 V regulator would be adequate. You could do something like what is being done for the 3 V supply (resistor divider and capacitor) but you would need to sacrifice some current. How much? I can't say without specs.

Comment: Why not run the opamp from 15V?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case there are different possibilities. One of the easiest and safest option is to use linear regulators forrm the [78xx](https://www.ti.com/product/LM7800/part-details/LM7805CT/NOPB) family (at least as long as you're not too concerned with efficiency or need high current).

78xx are a family of linear regulators that is probably older than the average reader here :)

Take an LM7812 (they are available from many different manufacturers) for the 12V rail.

7803 are normally 3.3V output. But looking at your schematic, this could be ok as well. Just keep in mind, that linear regulators can get really hot if your current draw is higher than a few 10s of mA (a TO220 Case can dissapiate 1W-2W to ambient but will burn your fingers on touch). The 12V is not much of a problem because it only drops about 3V. So getting 300mA out of it should be no big issue (it will still get hot!). The 3V drops 12V, so don't try to get more than 50-100mA out of it.

Look at the datasheet on how to use them and don't forget to place the required capacitors close to the leads of the regulator (otherwise you might get oscillations under some conditions).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYoQXg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitor values above are relatively random but should be in the right ballpark. Look at the datasheet of your component to get the recommended values. Also, I've used the 12V to feed the 3.3V regulator to reduce the heat load on that one (adding load to the 12V one)

Comment: i can also use just the 12v if i can get seperate 12v and 3v outputs from it since i only have just one voltage source avaliable i can set it to 12 v if getting 3v from it is posssible with some kind of regulators

Comment: You can get as many different voltages as you want. Just use more linear regulators. You can also use an LM317 which can be "programmed" by using two resistors. This way you can get ANY output voltage you want. Keep in mind, that the regulators need a minimal voltage drop across. So you can't make 11.5V from 12V. "Normal" ones need around 2.5V, Low drop regulators (LDO) still around 1.25V...

Comment: @Joseph It *may* be possible to "split" 15V to get 12V+3V but it will be much more complicated, and you probably shouldn't try it until you understand what it means.

Comment: @user253751 true. That's why I suggested the tried and true linear regulators. They are a solution thet "just works" in most cases.